# Whats the most cross-browser method of embedding videos?

Tags: video, video-streaming

A client of mine wants to put some videos on their website. In the past I've always just converted the video to an FLV, and used something like LongTail Player to play it.

However, nowadays of course lots of people use smartphones such as the iPhone that don't play flash files - so whats the best option? Is it a case of choosing one format, or is it best to go with flash, and then provide a download for iPhone users? I have noticed on some websites I have been viewing on my iphone, you can click on the video and it launches in YouTubes video player - is this perhaps an option?

Views would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use the HTML video tag with an mp4 version, a webm version + a flash fallback using the mp4 file.

This covers pretty much everything.

Kroc Camen has an awesome example of this on his [video for everyone](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the JW Player will do both Flash and HTML5 for you.  But the codec is important too: Be sure to encode your media as **h264 Baseline Profile 3.0**.